Tap tool on holoviews Points allowing for selection of multiple points
I have the following code:
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')

points = hv.Points(np.random.randn(10, 2))

points.opts(
    tools=["tap"],
    size=10
)

Based on some examples and documentation online, I expect the following behavior: If I click on a point, that point is highlighted. If I then click on another point, the first point is "deselected", and the new point is highlighted. And if I click where there is no point, all points are deselected, and nothing is highlighted.
However, when I run the code on my end, it strangely allows me to "select" multiple points. If I click on one point and then another one, both points are highlighted.
I'm really at a loss as to what's going on here. Why is the tap tool not behaving as expected and as seen in the documentation?
I am on python=3.10, holoviews=1.19.1, bokeh=3.4.1
